# SQL Server 2008 R2 Stuck in Single User Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-deployment

Having executed a DB deploy (from a VS SQL Server database project) on a local database, which failed, the database has been left in a state where it has single user mode left on (the deploy runs as single user mode).

When I connect to it from SSMS and try something like the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

I get the error:

> Changes to the state or options of database 'MyDatabase' cannot be made at this time. The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.

I tried taking the database offline, which SSMS tells me succeeds, but it doesn't appear to actually do anything. So far, I've only been able to get around this by dropping and recreating the database (which is kind of okay, because it's only a local test database). However, I'd like to be able to reset the status.

How can I convince SQL Server to take this database out of single user mode?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

In first run following query in master database

```
exec sp_who
```

If you can't find the culprit, try

```
SELECT request_session_id FROM sys.dm_tran_locks 
WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID('YourDatabase')
```

Then kill all process that use your database with following query:

```
KILL spid
```

Then run following query:

```
USE Master
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: If you cannot find any suspicious looking entries in in the sp_who output, this query has helped me out - SELECT request_session_id FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE  resource_database_id = DB_ID('YourDatabase ')

Comment: @earthling42: I added your (very useful) query to the answer

Comment: I was stuck in a similar state. But I had several spid which were connected or in waiting state. I realized that the server(application) using the database was creating connections as soon as I killed an existing connection and my console would never get a connection in this manner. So, I had to shut down all such servers first such that they do not contend for a connection. Only then could I run the query mentioned successfully and recover.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below commands

First run these three commands

```
USE [master] 
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH
exec sp_dboption MyDBName, 'single user', 'FALSE';
```

Second run these two commands

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDBName SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT
ALTER DATABASE MyDBName SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Answer (score 3):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620/how-do-you-kill-all-current-connections-to-a-sql-server-2005-database), the code is:

```
use master
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

--do you stuff here 

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the same issue - the DB will allow neither of those staements

Comment: did you replace master with your database name? also, do you have admin privileges on the database you want to alter?

Comment: Just add, this is not the correct answer. Once the db is in single user mode *and* is occupied by a session, the alter database command will NOT succeed. You need to kill the session that is occupying the db first, and then you can alter db to multi_user mode.

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DAC (Dedicated Admin Connection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx)**. Make sure you have enabled it first
In SSMS type in admin: for Server Name
after connecting to master ALTER DATABASE  SET MULTI_USER

Answer (score -1):

To force the update use " with rollback immediate"

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE_NAME] SET MULTI_USER  with rollback immediate
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Same error.