# Detach database programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a database "D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF".
I am trying to detach or rename it, with this code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=Master;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn);
cmd.CommandText = @"sys.sp_detach_db D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF";
conn.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();
```

But getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '\'.

Answer (score 7):

In order to detach a database and at the same time solve the error

> Cannot detach the database 'YOUR_DATABASE' because it is currently in use

you can simply use the following code:

```
    private void DetachDatabase()
    {
        String databaseConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection sqlDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlDatabaseConnection.Open();
                string commandString = "ALTER DATABASE YOUR_DATABASE SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ALTER DATABASE YOUR_DATABASE SET SINGLE_USER EXEC sp_detach_db 'YOUR_DATABASE'";
                SqlCommand sqlDatabaseCommand = new SqlCommand(commandString, sqlDatabaseConnection);
                sqlDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that **YOUR_DATABASE** is sometimes written without the single quotes, and sometimes with the single quotes. Only replace **YOUR_DATABASE** with the name of your database without *.mdf* extension and leave the rest of the string as it is...

Thanks to this website: [Detach database dropping connections](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic870653-391-1.aspx)

And this website: [SQL Server – How to Detach a Database](http://sqlandme.com/2013/06/03/sql-server-how-to-detach-a-database/)

By the way, this worked for me on SQL SERVER 2014

Answer (score 6):

You left out a quote inside the query, and as @KyleHale pointed out - it needs to be the name of the database, not a path to it.

Change:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"sys.sp_detach_db D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF;";
```

to be:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"sys.sp_detach_db 'dbName'";
```

Comment: Also, sp_detach_db takes a database name (it must be a valid sysname value), not a file path.

Comment: Yep, missed that out. Updated my answer. Thanks for noting!

Comment: Thanks. But now this error : Cannot detach the database 'D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF' because it is currently in use.

Comment: My dbname is 'D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF'. when i attach the mdf file from directory, the database name was it.

Comment: The path is the name of your database? It is what you see on the left-hand side of SQL Management studio, where the databases are listed? That entire path?

Comment: If that is truly the case (I'm not even sure if that's possible), try wrapping it into an identifier. Like this: sys.sp_detach_db '[D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF]'

Comment: I think that \ was solved but But now this error : Cannot detach the database 'D:\MDF CONNECTION SAMPLE\BIN\DEBUG\HARMDATABASE.MDF' because it is currently in use.

Comment: Check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620/how-do-you-kill-all-current-connections-to-a-sql-server-2005-database

Answer (score 5):

How about using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210177.aspx)?

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` which is available when you have SQL Express or SQL Server installed on your dev machine.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

void Detach()
{
  Server smoServer = new Server("MSSQLSERVER2008");
  smoServer.DetachDatabase("HARMDATABASE", False);
}
```

Comment: I cant find  Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll in my system.

Comment: You need to add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo which is available when you have SQL Express or SQL Server installed on your dev machine.  Check out the SMO link above.