# How to drop a database when it's currently in use?

Tags: sql, sql-server

NB. I don't want to mark the check box in the wizard for deletion. This question's **strictly** about scripting the behavior.

When I run the following script to get a fresh start, I get the error that the database *Duck* can't be deleted because it's currently in use.

```
use Master
drop database Duck
drop login WorkerLogin
drop login AdminLogin
go
```

Be that as it may (even though I'm the only user currently in the system and I run no other queries but that's another story), I need to close all the existing connections. One way is to wait it out or restart the manager. However I'd like to script in that behavior so I can tell the stubborn server to *drop* the duck down. (Yes, "typo" intended.)

What do I need to add to the dropping statement?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try below code.

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [Duck] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE [Duck] ;
```

For deep discussion see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34265).

Comment: Works great in the restore scenario from bacpac. Ideal for dev environement, but I wouldn't do that in production

Answer (score 2):

You have to kill first all active connections before you can drop the database.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

--do you stuff here

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Kill_All_Active_Connections_To_A_Database

[How do you kill all current connections to a SQL Server 2005 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620/how-do-you-kill-all-current-connections-to-a-sql-server-2005-database)

Comment: What if I'm dropping the DB and **totally recreating** it? Do I still need to set it to multi user? Or is that the default for the new databases?

Comment: @KonradViltersten That is a default if the database is newly created no need to set, all you have to do is to manage your database users.

Answer (score 0):

if you're ssms tab is not currently on the db to be dropped (meaning you are in the master db), then these will help:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/sql-server-cannot-drop-database-dbname-because-it-is-currently-in-use-but-n

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34264/how-to-force-drop-database-in-sql-server-2008